Как реализовать условие с миддлваром express.json?
Всем привет.
Есть приложение на express. Все работает. Разумеется в app есть app.use(express.json()).
В приложение нужно добавить роут /uploads на который будут приходить большие запросы POST.
Понимаю что можно увеличить лимит, например так - app.use(express.json({ limit: '10mb' }).
Но также понимаю что тогда лимит увеличится для запросов на все роуты, а этого делать не хотелось бы. Хотелось бы увеличить для одного конкретного - для /uploads. Понимаю что нужно проверить path в rec и дальше, в зависимости от path, устанавливать лимит. Но тут я как-то завис. Не понимаю как это записать в коде.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Обычно в upload отправляют не JSON, а multipart/form-data, так что express.json его просто прогнорирует, а ловить этот запрос надо будет через multer (или что-нибудь другое) https://github.com/expressjs/multer

@AlexeyTen интересная идея. Спасибо. Посмотрю.

@AlexeyTen
Реализовал.
CORS для multipart на файлах в промежутке больше чем лимит для JSON, но до 25МБ, работает. Когда пробую отправлять файл 25МБ, начинает ругаться Request Entity too large.
Главное что пока не понимаю как поменять лимит для multipart. Не знаешь случайно?

Задайте новый вопрос и приложите релевантный код

@AlexeyTen
Разобрался. Nginx ругался.
Спасибо за готовность помочь.
